# 'StackAPI' throttling exception

Tags: support, api, throttling

I am trying to use [StackAPI](https://stackapps.com/questions/6841/stackapi-another-python-wrapper) to query your API. I am trying to fetch the top questions/answers from each of your Stack Exchange sites. Here is my code snippet. As you would note, I am making the thread sleep for 1 sec between queries and am not sure why I am being throttled.

```
for site_key in site_keys list:

    SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
    questions = SITE.fetch('questions', min=10, sort='votes')

    for quest in questions['items']:
        qq = quest['title']
        tags = quest['tags']
        #writer.writerow({'site': stacksite, 'post': qq + ' ' + ' '.join(tags)})
        #print qq, tags
        sleep(1.0) # Sleep for 1 second to avoid throttling.
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you honor the backoff and try to be gentle, you can still be throttled. The API contract doesn't guarantee you won't be throttled.

Comment: @rene: your comment about "even if you honor...you can be throttled", that's perhaps cruel? why offer an api if we cannot build a worthwhile & useful app around it?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of worthwhile and useful apps around so please don't exaggerate your issue. Point is: Your API call passes the ha-proxy and that has its own set of IP blocking and throttle rules. You have to hammer it hard but if you do it kicks in and stops your IP traffic at the front door for a while. And that one doesn't come with a warning.

Comment: What is this "`StackAPI`" that you speak of? And what language? Python?

Comment: Yes Python. http://stackapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @PeterMortensen it's a code written by private person (not SE staff) using the public SE API to read posts. I've added a link to the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you have provided enough information to fully troubleshoot. However, StackAPI respects the backoff parameter automatically. It does this in the `fetch` call.

By the time you are sleeping, you have already performed 5 API calls - all in `fetch`. The default number of items StackAPI retrieves is 500 items. Each page of the Stack Exchange API returns 100 items, so it's made the call 5 times (and respected any backoff needed to retrieve those results) to get you the 500 results in your variable.

You are simply sleeping between each item in your `questions` list. You aren't preventing throttling at that point.

---

You could be throttled for repeatedly running this over multiple sites in a short time frame. This seems likely based on your outer `for` loop.

You could also be hitting limits for not having an API key. You are limited to 300 API calls a day without the key. You can provide your key to StackAPI when you set up your `SITE`:

```
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key=APP_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

This will increase your quota to 10,000 API calls.

---

Source: I'm the author of StackAPI

Comment: What is the difference between APP_KEY and ACCESS_TOKEN? I registered my app, I found the app_key but couldn't find the access_token. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

The backoff parameter doesn't always have to do with the frequency of your requests. It may also depend on other factors like SQL server load on our end.

The [API docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) are pretty clear on this:

> A dynamic throttle is also in place on a per-method level. If an application receives a response with the `backoff` field set, it *must* wait that many seconds before hitting the same method again. For the purposes of throttling, all /me routes are considered to be identical to their /users/{ids} equivalent. Note that `backoff` is set based on a combination of factors, and may not be consistently returned for the same arguments to the same method. Additionally, all methods (even seemingly trivial ones) may return `backoff`.